# CloudKit Query: After Date and Not in Array

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I'm trying to query records from CloudKit that either have a newer `modificationDate` than what I have locally, or perhaps that I don't have at all.

The records I have already are stored in `recordNames`. The the date is `date`.

I can do this with two predicates like this:

```
//Modification Date
let predicateDate = NSPredicate(format: "modificationDate > %@", date)

//Records I have already
let predicateRecordName = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (recordName IN %@)",recordNames)

//Combined 'OR'
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateDate, predicateRecordName])
```

But when I try to combine this as a compound `OR` predicate, or combine them into a single predicate, I get an error:

> Invalid predicate... CKErrorDomain Code=12... is not a comparison predicate, ck_isComparisonError=true

I see in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery) that doing an `OR` predicate is not allowed. I'd love to not have to make two separate queries here. Any ideas on how I can pull this off?

Comment: I should note that I've tried inverting my query like this: `NOT(modificationDate <= %@ AND NOT (recordName IN %@))` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

'OR' option not working with predicates (I don't know if this is a bug of CloudKit). You have to make multiple queries.